# asp.net Allow single page to be viewed without authorisation

Tags: asp.net, iis

Possibly a stupid question:
I have a site, developed by an outside company, which requires logon for all pages.

We'd like to add a single page to the site that DOESN'T require the user to be logged in...so they can click the link on the logon page to view "T&C's" type info.

Is this possible?

(ASP.Net 4.0 on IIS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the ASP.Net membership providers you can specify this in the web.config file. Where for blocked pages you would expect:

```
<authorization>
    <allow roles="granted"/>
    <deny users ="*"/>
</authorization>
```

you can specify this per folder (or per page):

```
<location path="terms.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization> 
            <allow users ="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

to allow everyone access to this specific page.

Note that you can create a specific web.config in a folder in your website, these settings override the general web.config. This allows you to customize these settings per folder level.

Comment: How/where do I specify this per page/folder?

Comment: Site currently has
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".SHAUTH" defaultUrl="~/default.aspx" loginUrl="~/login.aspx"/>
  </authentication>

Comment: @BlueChippy: i included your final solution in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to oɔɯǝɹ for pointing me in the right direction:

Added this after my  node

```
<location path="terms.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this only have static content?  Is it the asp.net application dealing with authentication?

If so you can just upload a .html file containing simple HTML (and your T&C) which will be served no problem to anyone requesting it.

Comment: Yes, it needs dynamic content as well, needs to be ASPX page.

Comment: In that case theres a good chance you'll need access to the source code, do T&C really need to by dynamic?

Comment: No problem, have all the source code - in the future will want more "open" pages as well. - is it something to do with folders/config files?